# Prepositional phrase as adjective or adverb phrase?

Tags: grammar

### Please if any one could help
Thank you in advance

**Circle the adverb or adjective phrase in each sentence, then tell what kind it is.**

My question is : Which is the preposition phrase in the question below doing the function of adverb or adjective phrase ?
Many of the viewers responded **to the poll**.
I suggested (( to the poll )) = ADV phrase modifying the verb responded, but as you see one book mentioned it can be the focus on ( Many ) = pronoun and here ( of the viewers ) can tell who are those viewers ? = those who are responded to the poll and not other ones. So, perhaps it is understood on this way or on the way I mentioned first.
[image]

Comment: “To the poll” is a **preposition phrase** functioning as **complement** of “responded”. Note that “many” is a determiner and “of the viewers” is a preposition phrase functioning as its complement. Ignore the book. It's mixing up form and function. 'Preposition phrase' and 'adjective phrase are different phrase types, the former having a preposition as head, the latter an adjective. Both kinds can modify or complement nouns. In the cited example, the analysis of "of these books" is wrong for the same reason: it’s a preposition phrase functioning as complement (not modifier) of "many".

Comment: @Ahmad Mohammad  BillJ is giving the analysis to be found in what most grammarians consider the best authority on English grammar, the _Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_. If someone gives a conflicting answer from some other source, one cannot lightly claim that that can be taken as correct. What weight are you going to attach to 'other users' replies'? I'd be very wary if they weren't (or weren't quoting) published PhDs or professors, say (and usually fairly wary if they _were_)..